# Is it possible to specify the CSV quote character when exporting BQ tables?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am exporting tables using the following command `bq extract --destination_format=CSV --compression=GZIP --noprint_header <table> <gcs>`

I noticed that strings containing double quotes had double quotes appended upon export, and stumbled upon the reason in this thread: [Data between quotes and field separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418381/data-between-quotes-and-field-separator)

It seems like there was a way to change the quote character (per Jordan's comment in the answer) at one point in the past, but I cannot seem to find it today.

Is it currently possible to specify the quote character when exporting BQ tables as CSV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Jordan's comment was related to Load Jobs and not applicable for Extract Jobs

The option to try I see in your case is to replace all double quotes with single quotes (via SELECT REPLACE(field,...) ... FROM table ... with new table as destination) and then do extract for that modified table
Of course this assumes you can afford such substitution and it will not than break your product/app.

Below is simplified example of query you should run

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE (REPLACE(fieldWithIssue, '"', "'") AS fieldWithIssue)
FROM yourTable
```

First REPLACE is part of [`SELECT * REPLACE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select-replace) feature
Whereas second [`REPLACE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#replace) is just simple string function that replaces double quotes with single quotes