# How to force double quotes to be ignored when loading data from Google Cloud Storage into BigQuery using Python?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

We are trying to load data into BigQuery but double quotes are causing problems.

According to [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418381/data-between-quotes-and-field-separator), double quotes can be ignored by setting the parameter configuration.load.quote = "". Examples are given for how to do that from the command line.

We tried adding job_config.load.quote = "" but we receive an error that job_config doesn't have a method called load.

How do we set the load.quote parameter when using Python?

Here is our code so far:

```
dataset_id = 'our_dataset_id'
dataset_ref = bigquery_client.dataset(dataset_id)

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.skip_leading_rows = 0 
job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV

uri = 'gs://our/bucket/path.csv'

load_job = bigquery_client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri,
    dataset_ref.table('our_destination_table'),
    job_config=job_config
    )  
print('Starting job {}'.format(load_job.job_id))
load_job.result()
```

Answer (score 2):

We discovered that the parameters are not consistent between the command line commands and the Python API and that is why they were failing.

Add this line:

```
job_config.quote_character = ""
```

Here is a link to the Python parameters for the job configuration: https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.LoadJobConfig.quote_character